# Real time Dashboards with AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am building a dashboard that updates data from DB in realtime. There should be a uni-directional communication channel(mostly WebSocket) from server to subscribed client, where the server would post data in that channel. There should also be options to group clients.  I came across some of the AWS services that provide webSocket support(API gateway WebSocket, IoT core), please guide me to the right one.

Comment: There are not "many aws services" that enable you to handle websockets. Do you have IoT devices and use the other IoT services already -> IoT core. Do you have normal (e.g. web) API -> Api Gateway.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks. I work with web apps, so I could use API gateway WebSocket. I want to create separate channels for separate group of clients, is it possible in API gateway